# exported .csv file from workbench saves in textedit file format on Mac

Tags: mysql, csv, textedit

I successfully exported a file from workbench in .csv file format, only for it to save in textedit format on my Mac, making it impossible for Tableau to read the file. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Export it in a format the Tableau can interpret

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the .csv file extension to the file name before exporting